# Choosing the delta in the definition of a limit as the min of two possibilities

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Why is it that when proving that the limit converges to a point and we find two $\delta$ do we take the smaller of the two? For example when proving $\lim_{x \to 4} x^2 = 16$ we start with some scratch work showing that $|x^2-16| = |x+4||x-4| < \epsilon$ and then we say: note that when $\delta = 1$ we have that $0 < |x-4| < 1$ and thus $3 < x < 5$ so we can bound $|x+4|<9$ as such and finally we conclude that $|x-4||x+4| < 9|x-4|<\epsilon$ and $|x-4| < \frac{\epsilon}{9}$ so we set $\delta = min{\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{9}}\}$. Why is it the min and not the max since it should be true for anything smaller than the $\delta$ chosen? i.e., $0 < |x-4|< \frac{\epsilon}{9}
 < 1$ if $\frac{\epsilon}{9}< 1$ or vice versa.

Edit: Thank you all for the answers I completely understand what is going on. I wish I could give you all a check-mark but I cannot so I'm giving it to the longest answer for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of limit states that $f(x)$ has a limit $L$ at $x = a$ if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.  That is to say, for any **error** $\epsilon$ as small as we please, there is a (punctured) **neighborhood** of size $\delta$ around $a$ such that whenever $x$ is in this neighborhood of $a$, the value of the function at $x$ deviates from the limit $L$ by no more than the error.

See the following picture:

[image]

From top to bottom and left to right are the choices $\epsilon = 12$, $9$, $2$, and $0.5$.  The pink band represents the range of $y$-values for $y = f(x) = x^2$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, where in this case $L = 16$.  The purple vertical lines correspond to the endpoints of an interval for $x$ that guarantees that the function $f(x)$ will lie within the pink band.

Naturally, the smaller your error tolerance $\epsilon$, the narrower the pink band, and the narrower will be the $x$-interval for which the function's values will still be within the error.  But you will notice that the purple lines are not equidistant from the line $x = 4$.  The left endpoint seems to be farther away than the right, and this is because the function is curved, and the more curved it is, the more noticeable the difference.

Because this interval is not necessarily symmetric about the limit point $a$, but the $\delta$ corresponding to the neighborhood we choose *does* have to result in a symmetric interval around $x = a$, the best we can do is pick a more conservative (smaller) value for $\delta$ that assures that any point inside the neighborhood will still capture a portion of the curve that lies entirely within the pink band.

The point of arbitrarily choosing $\delta = 1$ and finding $3 < x < 5$, is to simply avoid the complexity of choosing a suitably small $\delta$ that depends on $\epsilon$ when $\epsilon$ is "large."  For instance, in the cases $\epsilon = 12$ and $9$ shown in the first and second pictures, the purple lines completely contain the interval $3 < x < 5$.  So if $\epsilon > 9$, then $\delta = 1$ can be chosen and we are assured that $f(x)$ for $3 < x < 5$ will be within $\pm 9$ units of $L$ (i.e., be in the pink band).

When $\epsilon$ is smaller than $9$, however, then we have to be more selective.  We can show that the choice $\delta = \epsilon/9$ works using the reasoning that you provided in your question.  Combining these two conditions leads to the choice $$\delta = \min\{1, \epsilon/9\},$$ because you must always take the narrower of the neighborhoods, or else you could have a case where the values of the function in that neighborhood will not remain within the pink band.

That said, this choice is not *optimal* in the sense that it is smaller than it "needs" to be.  The neighborhood of maximal size is given by
$$\delta = \sqrt{16 + \epsilon}.$$  This choice corresponds to the purple line on the right.  But in general, with more complicated functions, it may not be possible to pick something "nice."  The interval on which $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ may vary quite wildly.

Comment: What software did you use to get those graphs? And thank you for the response, it was extremely helpful!

Comment: @JoseLukas You are most welcome.  The figures were created in *Mathematica* version 12.

Answer (score 1):

From the scratch work you show two statements of the form

- If $|x-4| < \delta_1$, then "A" happens.
- If $|x-4| < \delta_2$, then "B" happens.

Now you want to choose a $\delta$ such that

- If $|x-4| < \delta$, then both "A" and "B" happen.

Do you now see why choosing $\delta=\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ will work (and why $\max\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ does not)?

> Basically, if $\delta=\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, then we have

> $|x-4|<\delta \le \delta_1$ so therefore ...

> $|x-4| < \delta \le \delta_2$ so therefore ...

Answer (score 0):

It is the $min$ because we need the $\delta$ to be both less than or equal to $1$ and less than or equal to $\frac{\epsilon}{9}$.  We need it to be less than or equal to $1$ for $|+4|<9$ and to be less than or equal to $\frac{\epsilon}{9}$  for $|−4|<\frac{\epsilon}{9}$. If you did max then you would only satisfy one and not both.